# How to properly thicken this flat 2D mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I'm trying to thicken this flat mesh of vertices and edges into a 3D object.

[image]

Some merged parts work but some parts don't process well. What I tried was convert the mesh into a 2D curve (<kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Curve*) and then used the curve's *Object Data Properties* and gave it some *Depth* under the *Geometry > Bevel* tab. Is there a better method to ticken my object as shown below? I would also like the open ends to taper if possible. I noticed that the resulting curve has duplicate curve points which cannot be merged causing this anomaly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well the problem in the marked area is that you have the curve coming from the left and taking a sharp turn back and the same with the curve coming from the right. And then ther is a short straight unconnected piece in the middle. The problem in general is that the curve has a lot of discontinuities since they cannot all simply be connected like in a mesh. I would go with the original mesh and a _Skin_ modifier followed by a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for looking into it! I just did an automatic "convert to curve" XD. Ok I will try that :)